# How do I remove quotation marks from java system properties

Tags: java, bash, escaping

I have a `bazinga` property stored in an environment variable

```
export OPTS="-Dbazinga=\"foo bar\""
```

```
-bash-4.1$ echo $OPTS
-Dbazinga="foo bar"
```

Also, there is an example java program that just prints its value:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("bazinga", ""));
    }
}
```

When I run the program without using the env variable everything works fine, meaning `foo bar` is printed:

```
-bash-4.1$ java -Dbazinga="foo bar" Main
foo bar
```

However, I am unable to run the program using the variable because qoutation marks get in the way:

```
-bash-4.1$ java $OPTS Main
Error: Could not find or load main class bar"

-bash-4.1$ java "$OPTS" Main
"foo bar"
```

How can I run the program using the env variable with correct quotation marks handling?

Comment: I’m not sure backslashes work in Unix shells the same way they work in Java code.  Try defining the environment variable this way:  `export OPTS="-Dbazinga='foo bar'"`

Comment: Now it prints `'foo bar'`

Comment: Even when you run it using `java $OPTS Main` without any quotes in the command line?

Comment: When I run `java $OPTS Main` then I get `Error: Could not find or load main class bar'`

Comment: I suppose that makes sense;  the quotes in an expanded value are just text, not shell metacharacters.  You can do `bash -c "java $OPTS Main"`, though I’m not particularly fond of that since it can introduce other problems, should your case become more complex.

Comment: See [Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia) (and many similar questions).